Spring Security error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
I'm doing a small project in JAVA, I'm using Spring Security for authentication, but when I try to run my code, it gives me the following Error Stack:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'adminUserConfig' defined in file [C:\Users\Matheus Castilho\Desktop\projetos\BookStoreAPI\target\classes\com\br\BookStoreAPI\config\AdminUserConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at com.br.BookStoreAPI.BookStoreApiApplication.main(BookStoreApiApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'PUBLIC_KEY' in value "${PUBLIC_KEY}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:230) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:80) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:61) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:552) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:153) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:149) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getPropertyAsRawString(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:74) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:153) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:200) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1374) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    ... 40 common frames omitted

My securityConfig like this:
package com.br.BookStoreAPI.config;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.HeadersConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Value("${jwt.public}")
    private String publicKey;
    @Value("${jwt.private}")
    private String privateKey;

    @Bean
    public RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey() throws Exception {
        String cleanedKey = publicKey
                .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
                .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
                .replaceAll("\\s+", "");

        if (cleanedKey.startsWith("ssh-rsa")) {
            String[] parts = cleanedKey.split("\\s+");
            if (parts.length >= 2) {
                cleanedKey = parts[1];
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Formato de chave ssh-rsa inválido");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Public Key (cleaned): " + cleanedKey); // Para debug

        byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cleanedKey);
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decoded);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
    }

    @Bean
    public RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey() throws Exception {
        String privateKeyPEM = privateKey
                .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replaceAll("\\s+", "");

        System.out.println("Private Key PEM: " + privateKeyPEM); // Para debug

        byte[] encoded = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(privateKeyPEM);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users/register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .oauth2ResourceServer( oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() throws Exception {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaPublicKey()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() throws Exception {
        RSAKey key = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaPublicKey()).privateKey(rsaPrivateKey()).build();
        ImmutableJWKSet keys = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(key));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(keys);
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

And my pom.xml like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.br</groupId>
    <artifactId>BookStoreAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>BookStoreAPI</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I have already downloaded the dependencies again, hoping that would be the case but I got the same error.

Reading this
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Could not resolve placeholder 'PUBLIC_KEY' in value "${PUBLIC_KEY}"

Generally it means that Spring can't find an environment variable called PUBLIC_KEY that is referenced to set an internal property. I suppose that in your application.properties file you have something similar to this:
jwt.public=${PUBLIC_KEY}

I suggest you to check if this PUBLIC_KEY environment variable is set, or if this is the correct name that has to be used for setting the internal properties of your beans.

[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6] ... 19 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'PUBLIC_KEY' in value "${PUBLIC_KEY}" at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180)

From the error message, the error cause by mismatch in name used in property file and SecurityConfig class. Please look into application.properties file and write the corresponding name in @Value() in SecurityConfig.
